# why the google maps camera not in my location?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have code for google maps in fragment android , i want the camera in my location but the camera is in other location and i dont know why this happen 
anyone can help me find out why this situation happen

This is my fragment code :

```
public class FragmentMap extends Fragment implements LocationListener {

MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;
double latitude;
double longitude;
public String bestProvider;
public Criteria criteria;


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    // Getting latitude of the current location
    latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    criteria = new Criteria();
    bestProvider = String.valueOf(MainActivity.locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true)).toString();
    Location location = MainActivity.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate =
            CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}
```

}

This is my location declaration  :

```
public static LocationManager locationManager;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Where is the map located now and did you call map.invalidate()?

Comment: the location of the gps is right but the camera is wrong

Comment: best tutorial  http://www.adavis.info/2014/09/android-location-updates-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your onlocationchange should be -

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                .zoom(14)
                .build();

if (map != null) {
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}

}
```

this will move camera to your present location.

let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: still not working bro still miss camera position :( i try debug the long and lat 1st now

Comment: is the onlocationchange is being called ?

Comment: i know the long and latitude is wrong how to get the right longitude and latitude ?

Comment: hey buddy , do you know how the locationlistener works ? this gives you a location fetched from gps satellites. so this might give exact location and wrong location sometimes. because you would be having signal problem. so to open field and check it. it will give you exact location

Comment: and the googlemap camera moves to that location which location is provided by locationlistener. so it all depends on locationlistener. if this method is being called and your google maps is all right. then you are good to go.

Comment: can you accept this as correct answer if this solution worked for you.

Comment: just delete this row
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate =
            CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
all done